# Open a file from url, path contains wildcard characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can open a local file with wildcard characters like this:

```
  require 'nokogiri'  
  require 'open-uri'
  Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("public/system/xmls/**/original/*.xml")).each do |path|
  File.open(path) do |f|      
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
  #etc
```

But this doesn't work of course:

```
  Dir.glob("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foldername/xmlimports/**/*.xml").each do |path| #etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL's don't offer a standardized way of listing a directory's contents, so it's impossible to write a glob handler that'll work for any URL. You'll have to roll your own glob handler for this particular case, or rely on something like `wget` to mirror the entire directory and glob the files locally (but that would be a bizarre approach if the files are large and/or you need to process just few of them).

Comment: Harrumph. Thanks for that though, saved me hours of trying an impossible task. I'll rethink my approach and pass in a variable of the recently uploaded file, I think.